# Objective C: Asynchronous loading of some data -> I want to update afterwards labels

Tags: ios, objective-c, parallel-processing

I am a bit confused. I have written a class, that calculates some stuff and makes an internet query. Afer this query some NSString properties of this class are updated with the resulting values.

In my view controller, I create an instance of this class. I want to show in the labels waiting for text "Loading..." until the data has arrived. As soon as the data is ready, I want to replace the text. But how do I do that? And depending on if one property, I also want to redraw one view of this view controller. Furthermore I don't want to block my UI.

This so far hasn't worked...

```
self.firstLabel.text = @"Loading...";
self.secondLabel.text = @"Loading...";

UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
[indicator setColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"3375cb"]];
indicator.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:indicator];
[indicator startAnimating];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self.myInstance fillLabelsWithLiveData];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [indicator stopAnimating];
        self.firstLabel.text = myInstance.someText;
        self.secondLabel.text = myInstance.someMoreText;
        if(myInstance.myBool){
            //redraw
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Most likely `fillLabelsWithLiveData` completes asynchronously (but you haven't shown that code) so you are putting the new values into your labels before they have been set. You need to pass a completion handler block to `fillLabelsWithLiveData` so that you can set the labels once it has finished

Answer (score 0):

You say that your code isn't working, but you don't say what the actual behaviour is, so I would like to write about how I would debug the code in order to see where the problem is.

First, I would put a few log statements into the code, in order to see what it actually does.

```
NSLog(@"MyViewController: Starting to load...");
self.firstLabel.text = @"Loading...";
self.secondLabel.text = @"Loading...";

UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
[indicator setColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"3375cb"]];
indicator.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:indicator];
[indicator startAnimating];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSLog(@"MyViewController: Starting to load on background queue...");
    [self.myInstance fillLabelsWithLiveData];
    NSLog(@"MyViewController: Done loading on background queue...");

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"MyViewController: Updating main queue UI");
        [indicator stopAnimating];
        self.firstLabel.text = myInstance.someText;
        self.secondLabel.text = myInstance.someMoreText;
        if(myInstance.myBool){
            NSLog(@"MyViewController: Will redraw...");
            //redraw
        } else {
            NSLog(@"MyViewController: Will not redraw (myInstance.myBool is NO)");
        }
    });
});
```

When you do this you will see where the problem lies exactly. (Note that in tutorials all over the internet, the log messages are often ultra short. Like `NSLog(@"loading...");`. The problem is that if you have many logs in your app and every class logs like this, the log messages become useless. What's worse, you may see that "loading..." is printed on the console and assume that your code is called, when in fact some other place in the program prints "loading...". So I always add some context to `NSLog` calls. (In fact, I never use `NSLog`, I use custom logging libraries that also print file names and line numbers.))

Just a few comments on your code.

### centering the indicator

```
indicator.center = self.view.center; // (1a)
```

This does not center the indicator in self.view

```
indicator.center = centerOf(self.view.bounds); // (1b)
```

does. You have to define centerOf:

```
CGPoint centerOf(CGRect rect) {
    CGFloat x = CGRectGetMidX(rect);
    CGFloat y = CGRectGetMidY(rect);
    return CGPointMake(x, y);
}
```

(1a) works sufficiently well though if `self.view.frame.origin` is sufficiently near to (0, 0).

### check if your code hangs

If you add the logs and look into the console, there are a few things that can go wrong:

- The new log lines do not show up at all => in this case, you should check why your code isn't called at all
- The new log lines are printed up to some point, e.g. "Done loading on background queue" is never printed to the console. => In this case, the code that is in-between hangs, obviously.
- The logs look good, but the indicator doesn't show up. 2 options:

  - everything is so fast that you just don't see the indicator.
  - the loading on the background queue takes some time, but the indicator is not visible => is the superview of the indicator visible? Use the "inspect view hierarchy" feature of Xcode to check what is going on. Where is your view? Add some code like `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];` to see if it makes a difference.
- The logs look good, but the labels did not update.

  - if this is the case, I cannot help you anymore. You didn't post the real code. You posted a simplified version of it, and the bug hides behind that simplification.